# Why can I not iterate over this object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am trying to iterate over an object, but the jquery $.each won't fire.
This is the outcome of the $fileNames variable:

[image: This is the outcome of the $fileNames variable]

and this is the code I've built so far:

```
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
$searchtag = '';
$files = '';
$fileNames = {};

// first get all files in the directory
$.ajax({
  url: "php/cse.php",
  data: "requestFileNames=true",
  method: "POST",
  success: function(result){
    $result = JSON.parse(result).toString();
    $result += ",";
    $count = ($result.match(/o/g)||[]).length + 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= $count; i++) {
      $fname = $result.substr(0, $result.indexOf(','));
      $fileNames[$fname] = {};
      $result = $result.replace($fname + ",", "");
    }
  }
});

console.log($fileNames);
$.each($fileNames, function(key, value){
  // this does not fire, for some reason.
});
```

});

Why is it not working?

Comment: *Hint: **asynchronous**.*

Comment: $.ajax is asynchronous

Comment: So, why can I console log it, but not iterate thought it? Doesn't make sense. I get what asyncronous means, but this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: also ... `JSON.parse(result).toString();` will ALWAYS result in the value **"[object Object]"** - which is probably not what you want

Comment: `console.log()` is always going to get called before the callback `success()` handler where you have it. Move the `console.log()` and `$.each()` into the `success()` handler and you *might* see different results (depending on if the `$.ajax()` request returns anything).

Comment: Also, you should be initialising new variables with `var`

Comment: @JaredFarrish This is not the question, THAT works as shown in the image (it needs improvement, sure, but not my question). My question is; Why can I not iterate through this seemingly normal object?

Comment: Ahh. Because the `console` will update the object once you open and view it. so it *appears* it was there, but at the time `console.log()` was called, it was empty. Confirm by logging `console.log(JSON.stringify($fileNames))` instead. I myself think this is confusing and is done for memory considerations AFAICT.

Comment: It works when I put it in the succes handler, BUT, why does the console log work, eventhough it's not in the succes handler, but the .each doesn't? Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thank you! The explanation I was looking for! :)

Comment: You can also open the console and run `var a = {a:1,b:2,c:3}`, then log it. You'll see the response includes the key/value pairs, whereas the screenshot indicates an empty object.

Answer (score -2):

Make async false, but this will pause the code.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "php/cse.php",
      data: "requestFileNames=true",
      method: "POST",
      **async: false,**
      success: function(result){
        $result = JSON.parse(result).toString();
        $result += ",";
        $count = ($result.match(/o/g)||[]).length + 1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= $count; i++) {
          $fname = $result.substr(0, $result.indexOf(','));
          $fileNames[$fname] = {};
          $result = $result.replace($fname + ",", "");
        }
      }
    });
```

Or call the function (i.e. $.each()) within success or complete method

Comment: Very, very rarely is it suggested to use `async: false`.